# How to split a text file to its words in python?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and also didn't work with text before...I have 100 text files, each has around 100 to 150 lines of unstructured text describing patient's condition. I read one file in python using:

```
with open("C:\\...\\...\\...\\record-13.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    print (content)
```

Now I can split each line of this file to its words using for example:

```
a = content[0].split()
print (a)
```

but I don't know how to split whole file to words?
do loops (while or for) help with that?

---

Thank you for your help guys. Your answers help me to write this (in my file, words are split by space so that's delimiter I think!):

```
with open ("C:\\...\\...\\...\\record-13.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
      words = line.split()
      for word in words:
          print (word)
```

that simply splits words by line (one word in one line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody has suggested a generator, I'm surprised. Here's how I would do it:

```
def words(stringIterable):
    #upcast the argument to an iterator, if it's an iterator already, it stays the same
    lineStream = iter(stringIterable)
    for line in lineStream: #enumerate the lines
        for word in line.split(): #further break them down
            yield word
```

Now this can be used both on simple lists of sentences that you might have in memory already:

```
listOfLines = ['hi there', 'how are you']
for word in words(listOfLines):
    print(word)
```

But it will work just as well on a file, without needing to read the whole file in memory:

```
with open('words.py', 'r') as myself:
    for word in words(myself):
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how you define `words`, or what you regard as the `delimiters`.
Notice `string.split` in Python receives an optional parameter `delimiter`, so you could pass it as this:

```
for lines in content[0].split():
    for word in lines.split(','):
        print(word)
```

Unfortunately, `string.split` receives a single delimiter only, so you may need multi-level splitting like this:

```
for lines in content[0].split():
    for split0 in lines.split(' '):
        for split1 in split0.split(','):
            for split2 in split1.split('.'):
                for split3 in split2.split('?'):
                    for split4 in split3.split('!'):
                        for word in split4.split(':'): 
                            if word != "":
                                print(word)
```

Looks ugly, right? Luckily we can use iteration instead:

```
delimiters = ['\n', ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', 'and_what_else_you_need']
words = content
for delimiter in delimiters:
    new_words = []
    for word in words:
        new_words += word.split(delimiter)
    words = new_words
```

**EDITED:** 
Or simply we could use the regular expression package:

```
import re
delimiters = ['\n', ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', ':', 'and_what_else_you_need']
words = re.split('|'.join(delimiters), content)
```

Comment: when I wanna use the regular expression package, I face this error: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @MACEE Sorry that was my mistake. Corrected. Please check it again.

Comment: First solution splits words into separate letters (I run it with `words = "test string     aaaaa\n\n\nfinal."`), second crashes as special regexp characters are not escaped.

Answer (score 8):

```
with open("C:\...\...\...\record-13.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            print word
```

Or, this gives you a list of words

```
with open("C:\...\...\...\record-13.txt") as f:
    words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
```

Or, this gives you a list of lines, but with each line as a list of words.

```
with open("C:\...\...\...\record-13.txt") as f:
    words = [line.split() for line in f]
```

Comment: Missing colon. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Natural Language Tool Kit](http://www.nltk.org) as the `split()` way does not deal well with punctuation.

```
import nltk

for line in file:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible approach is to use list comprehension to generate a list of words:

```
with open("C:\...\...\...\record-13.txt") as f:
    words = [word
             for line in f
             for word in line.split()]

# Do what you want with the words list
```

Which you can then iterate over, add to a `collections.Counter` or anything else you please.

Comment: Aren't the loops in the list comprehension in the wrong order?