# How to replace multiple strings with one string with downcase in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, str-replace

I need to write a function which replaces multiple format strings into downcase.

For example, a paragraph contains a word 'something' in different formats like 'Something', 'SomeThing', 'SOMETHING', 'SomeTHing' need to convert all format words into downcase 'something'.

How to write a function with replacing with downcase?

Comment: Hi Prasanna. Could you please post some sample code to show what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using replace method which is not efficient. eg: output.replace("SomeThing", "something").replace("SomeTHing", "something")

Answer (score 2):

You can split your paragraph into different words, then use the [slugify](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slugify) module to generate a slug of each word, compare it with **"something"**, and if there is a match, replace the word with "something".

```
In [1]: text = "This paragraph contains Something, SOMETHING, AND SomeTHing"

In [2]: from slugify import slugify

In [3]: for word in text.split(" "): # Split the text using space, and iterate through the words
   ...:     if slugify(unicode(word)) == "something": # Compare the word slug with "something"
   ...:           text = text.replace(word, word.lower())

In [4]: text
Out[4]: 'This paragraph contains something, something AND something'
```

Comment: Now you don't have any commas, dots etc in the output text. That was not desired.

Comment: @Psytho Nice catch. Rectified it now.

Answer (score 1):

Split the text into single words and check whether a word in written in lower case is "something". If yes, then change the case to lower

```
if word.lower() == "something":
    text = text.replace(word, "something")
```

To know how to split a text into words, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720311/how-to-split-a-text-file-to-its-words-in-python).

Another way is to iterate through single letters and check whether a letter is the first letter of "something":

```
text = "Many words: SoMeThInG, SOMEthING, someTHing"
for n in range(len(text)-8):
    if text[n:n+9].lower() == "something": # check whether "something" is here
        text = text.replace(text[n:n+9], "something")

print text
```

Comment: The second way is simple and elegant. Didn't think about that!

Comment: It could be slow if the text is very long, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall) to search and split the paragraph into words and punctuation, and replace all the different cases of `"Something"` with the lowercase version:

```
import re

text = "Something, Is: SoMeThInG, SOMEthING, someTHing."

to_replace = "something"

words_punct = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;: ]", text)

new_text = "".join(to_replace if x.lower() == to_replace else x for x in words_punct)

print(new_text)
```

Which outputs:

```
something, Is: something, something, something.
```

**Note:** `re.findall` requires a hardcoded regular expression to search for contents in a string. Your actual text may contain characters that are not in the regular expression above, you will need to add these as needed.